# Why I cannot use this parameter?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to use the "id" in both selects on the UNION, is there any way to do it?

```mysql
SELECT id, name, (

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.time_added, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'last_update' FROM analysis_groups ag, analysis_group_relation agr, analysis a WHERE ag.id = id AND agr.group_id = ag.id AND a.id = agr.analysis_id AND a.type != 3
    UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.time_added, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'last_update' FROM analysis_groups ag, analysis_group_relation agr, analysis a, user_analysis ua WHERE agr.group_id = ag.id AND a.id = agr.analysis_id AND a.type = 3 AND ua.analysis_id = a.id AND a.id = '5bf1d6c5242f1' ORDER BY last_update LIMIT 1
) AS last_update_date 

FROM analysis_groups WHERE id != '0' ORDER BY last_update_date DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: AFAIK the two `UNION`'ed `SELECT`s in your query are actually a subquery to the outer `SELECT` statement, and you can't have a subquery return more than one row like that. Are you getting an error message? What does it say? Also, consider simplifying your code by removing non-essential column and table names. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Marc.2377 Actually is not returning more than one row, there is a LIMIT at the end of the UNION. I'm having this: #1052 - Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Ah, indeed, but I'm afraid the `LIMIT` clause is in fact at the end of *one* component of the UNION, when it should be at the end of both (or perhaps moving it outside of the ending parenthesis should work; I can't test it right now - and maybe you'll also want to do the same with the ORDER BY clause). Concerning your main error, though, I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: It makes sense but not working. LIMIT at the end of the UNION is effecting to the absolute UNION query, I mean: It attachs the two SELECTS and from these 5 registers (for ex.) it gets the first one, isn't it?? Thanks for your answering @Marc.2377

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it appears I was wrong regarding the positioning of the `LIMIT` clause. Not really familiar with the MySQL syntax, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer would be: Define an alias for `analysis_groups` in the main query, and reference it in the `WHERE` clause, like this

```
SELECT id, name, (

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.time_added, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'last_update' FROM analysis_groups ag, analysis_group_relation agr, analysis a WHERE ag.id = ag2.id AND agr.group_id = ag.id AND a.id = agr.analysis_id AND a.type != 3
    UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.time_added, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'last_update' FROM analysis_groups ag, analysis_group_relation agr, analysis a, user_analysis ua WHERE agr.group_id = ag.id AND a.id = agr.analysis_id AND a.type = 3 AND ua.analysis_id = a.id AND a.id = '5bf1d6c5242f1' ORDER BY last_update LIMIT 1
) AS last_update_date 

FROM analysis_groups ag2 WHERE id != '0' ORDER BY last_update_date DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot!